# I think my Gmail has been hacked!

Tags: gmail

I think my Gmail has been hacked. I tried logging in but it wouldn't accept my password so I thought I had probably changed it before and can't remember it so I decided to change it and it asked me to put my phone number. I did but it didn't accept it, the last two digits it gave me were "83" and I don't know any number that ends with those two digits.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you can do. None of us can help you recover an account that could have been compromised. The good thing is you're using Google. Which has better support than any other mail service. Microsoft is a close second.

What you're going to need to do is [contact google](http://www.google.com/contact/) on the phone is your best bet. They have been able to recover my brothers account that was compromised. When I did it for him they asked a series of questions regarding his account and other information regarding his account. Such as name birthdate past passwords etc. Although they may no longer offer this service over the phone but you must ask. It's a time sensitive matter if your account has been compromised.
Also a big concern to me: If your account is for sure compromised and you haven't physically gave someone your password you will need to virus scan vigorously and look for keyloggers or other information stealing viruses. Make sure there are no suspicious recent downloads you accidentally downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is the best and I will tell you why.

When they ask for your phone number, do not put it in. There will be an option somewhere down stating "Try different method to reset password".

Choose it, they will ask you for old passwords. Try your luck there.

If you don't remember it then say so, there is a option for that too.

Use the device and the network which you used last time to do this process, they track IP addresses of previous sessions.

They will ask all sorts of details about your account like linked accounts, numbers, birthdate, etc.

In the end, as the other answer says, you can contact them via the same process (if the info you provide is not 100% correct, they will provide this option automatically).
This process involves further details which only the owner knows.

Good luck and if possible, share your experiance here for future visitors.